# VueJS спарсить HTML

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

Есть страница со списком товаров, которые генереруются на PHP 
Хочу на JS собрать все необходимые данные по каждому товару: название, цена и другие. 
Потом на основе этих данных сгенерировать на VueJS карточки товара с другой разметкой. 
Я на js-фреймворках новичок. Пока только придумал создать компонент:

```
Vue.component('newProduct', {
    template: `Здесь вся новая разметка товара`
});
```

И в него вставлять данные по каждой карточке товара, полученные гипотетически вот таким образом:

```
data: {
goods: [{
        title: $('.titleProduct').text(),
        price: $('.priceProduct').text()
        },{
        title: $('.titleProduct').text(),
        price: $('.priceProduct').text()
    }] 
}
```

Не знаю как во вью правильно парсить... поэтому банально собрать по всему html как-нибудь данные
И потом размножить компонент на полученное количество товаров:

```
<newProduct v-for="product in goods"></newProduct>
```

Предложите, пожалуйста, ваши варианты как это можно сделать проще именно на Vue. Может есть какие-то стандартные практики? Понятно, что правильнее сделать это на PHP, но нужно именно с этим фреймворком.

Comment: Ваш вариант похоже единственный, потому что все данные о товарах находятся в разметке и, даже генерируя шаблон Vue, вы должны предоставить компоненту эти данные.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1 вариант**

Один из распространенных вариантов, когда сервер по адресу `/api/v1/products` возвращает данные в формате **json**. Ваше приложение, написанное на vuejs, взаимодействуем с сервером посредством ajax запроса с использованием обертки axios.

**2 вариант**

Еще один из вариантов - это передавать начальные данные в js до инициализации vue приложения, без необходимости их парсить/собирать по документу.

```
<script>
var scriptVariables = {
  products: <?= json_encode($arrayProductsFromPhp) ?>
}

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    // Наша модель с товарами.
    // Берем из глобальной переменной.
    products: scriptVariables.products
  },
  ... Остальной код.
  ... В третьем варианте подробнее.
})
</script>
```

**3 вариант**

Vuejs не предоставляет каких-то специальных инструментов для парсинга html. Но есть специальный атрибут `ref` для html тегов, который предоставляет прямой доступ к экземплярам дочерних компонентов и элементам. Нутром чувствую, что это сродни `document.getElemntBy...`.

Так как вы только начали изучать vuejs думаю, вам будет интересен в качестве примера следующий код:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data: {
    // Наша модель с товарами. Изначально это пустой массив.
    products: []
  },

  computed: {
    /**
     * В моделе содержится хоть один товар.
     */
    issetProducts() {
      return Boolean(this.products.length)
    }
  },

  /**
   * Используем хук `mounted` для инициализации сбора данных.
   * Возможно, что в реальном проекте нужно будет воспользоваться
   * async/await и возвращать Promise из метода `parseHtml`.
   */
  mounted() {
    // Запускаем парсинг.
    this.parseHtml()

    // Тут можем добавть класс к прелоадеру, чтобы скрыть его или удалить.
  },

  methods: {
    parseHtml() {
      // Для доступа к dom используем назначенную ранне ссылку:
      // <table ref="productsTable">
      let table = this.$refs.productsTable

      this.parseHtmlTable(table)
      this.removeTable(table)
    },

    /**
     * Парсинг таблицы по ссылке. Никакой магии: native javascript.
     */
    parseHtmlTable(table) {
      // Выбираем первый body из таблицы: HTMLCollection [tbody].
      let firstTableBody = table.tBodies[0]

      // Получаем списоk всех строк из tBody.
      let rows = firstTableBody.rows

      // Проходимся по: HTMLCollection(4) [tr, tr, tr, tr].
      // Не будем мудрить, т.к. мы знаем,
      // что первая ячейка в строке - это название, вторая - цена.
      for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        // Добавляем данные в нашу модель товаров `products`.
        this.products.push({
          id: i + 1, // Насколько это правильно?
          title: rows[i].cells[0].innerText,
          price: rows[i].cells[1].innerText,
        })
      }
    },

    /**
     * Скрываем/очищаем/удаляем таблицу из документа.
     */
    removeTable(table) {
      table.setAttribute('style', 'display:none')
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <!--Здесь лучше разместить какой-нибудь div-ный прелоадер на всю страницу. -->
  <!-- Используем атрибут `ref` для регистрации ссылки и доступа к dom из vuejs. -->
  <table ref="productsTable">
    <caption>Список товаров с первоначальной разметкой</caption>
    <tbody>
      <tr><td>Первый товар</td><td>560</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Второй товар</td><td>890</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Третий товар</td><td>354</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Четвертый товар</td><td>159</td></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <!-- В рамках примера не будем выносить в отдельный компонент. -->
  <h2 v-if="issetProducts">Список товаров с разметкой из vuejs</h2>
  <template v-for="product in products" :key="product.id">
    <p>{{ product.title }} <sup>{{ product.price }} фантик(ов)</sup></p>
  </template>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
```

Comment: спасибо большое, за подробный ответ. Я выбрал второй вариант, но доработаю код с помощью третьего варианта